# UWP Caliburn.Micro 2 x ActiveItem, How to do activate for 2 screens at same time?

Tags: c#, uwp, caliburn.micro

in Caliburn.Micro, We can "active" a view in Parent-View.

To activate a screen in Parent-View,
It's easy.

```
ActivateItem(new Child1ViewModel());
```

just it. but How to activate 2 view in same parent ?

[image]

Comment: Assuming that `ParentViewModel` is derived from `Conductor<object>.Collection.AllActive` then activating an item does not de-activate the previously active item. You can have more than one item active at the same time.

Comment: Your class should derive from `Conductor<T>.Collection.AllActive` and then you can use `Items` property from derived class to add multiple screens.

Answer (score 1):

The comment answers are correct here, having `ParentViewModel` inherit from `Conductor<T>.Collection.AllActive` should get you the result you need.

If you really don't need all the collection functionality provided by the class above you can just use something like the following in the constructor of `ParentViewModel`.

```
ActiveItem.ConductWith(this);
```

This will just wire the Activate event from `ParentViewModel` to activate the child. Ditto with deactivate.

Comment: Still having issue , The View is not instantiating . I have created property with same name of "ChildViewModel" then gave same name for ContentControl . I have initialize ChildviewModel then assign to new property and activated , still its not showing.Do you have any idea or example ?

Comment: Can you get a GitHub repo with your problem and I'll take a look.